# Can't load xits-math.otf file in lualatex; missing \endcsname insterted

Tags: fonts, luatex, unicode-math

Here's a MWE of the problem I'm talking about. I'm using the lualatex command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\setmathfont[Path=~/texmf,
             Extension=.otf,
            ]{xits-math}


\end{document}
```

I get the following output:

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "script-not-exist"
* 
* Font 'xits-math' does not contain script 'Math'.
*************************************************

*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Style=MathScript' (+ssty) not available for font
* 'xits-math' with script 'Math' and language 'Default'.
*************************************************

*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Style=MathScriptScript' (+ssty) not available for font
* 'xits-math' with script 'Math' and language 'Default'.
*************************************************
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
\protect 
l.8             ]{xits-math}
```

I'm using the file from the XITS github. I am trying to use this font because Latin Modern Math doesn't have a character that I want and XITS Math does, but I have been completely unable to figure out how to successfully load the font.

Comment: Try `Path=\string~/texmf,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unsure why you have to use a private copy of `xits-math.otf`, as it is distributed with TeX Live.

Anyhow, you need `\string~`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[
  Path=\string~/texmf/,
  Extension=.otf,
]{xits-math}

\begin{document}

$a+b=c$

\end{document}
```

I get, in the terminal and the log file,

```
</Users/MASKED/texmf/xits-math.otf>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer worked!

When I tried to include it, it didn't find the font. That's why I got a private copy.